# Play video with subtitle by vlc

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, vlc

i tried to play video and subtitle by vlc.

my code:

```
Process.Start("path to vlc", "videofile.avi, subtitles.srt")
```

not working.

what is the right way to do it?.

Solution:

```
Process.Start("C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe", "file:///C:/P2.avi --sub-file=file:///C:/123.srt")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Process.Start("path to VLC", "videofile.avi --sub-file=subtitles.srt");
```

Comment: File reading failed:
VLC could not open the file "c:\P2.avi,". (%m)
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///c:/P2.avi%2C'. Check the log for details.

Comment: Sorry, remove the comma from the arguments. I've updated the post.

Comment: thank you, is working.is not working without "file:///path to file" (edit your answer)

Answer (score 0):

The solution shown [here](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/issues/543#issuecomment-478665591) works properly for me:

Set the subtitle file as the option of the "SetMedia()" method. Note that use `new string[] { @"sub-file=your subtitle file address}`